# Agent Client relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to develop an application where one user (called Agent) after registering with the website can create many clients. I am using MVC5 and ASP.NET Identity. What I want to know is that when Agent is working with a particular client, do I need to store the Client id in session or every time I send the id in query string or something like that to identify the current client on which the agent is working on. I Would really appreciate if someone can guide me in right direction.

SAMPLE CLASSES ARE LIKE THIS

```
public class Agent
{
  public int UserId{get; set;}
  public ICollection<Client> Clients{get; set;}

  public virtual ApplicationUser User{get; set;}
}

public class Client
{
  public int ClientId{get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set}
  public Address Address{get; set;}
  public Something1 Something1{get; set;}
  public Something2 Something2{get; set;}
  so on....

  public int UserId{get; set;}
  public virtual Agent Agent{get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
  public int ClientId{get; set;}
  public string Line1{get; set}
  public string Line2{get; set}
  public string PostCode{get; set}


  public virtual Client Client{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per REST-guidelines, the client is a resource and should be identified by the URL. For example, `/clients/{clientId}` for details, `/clients/{clientId}/edit` to modify, `/clients/{clientId}/delete` to delete, etc.

Your action would take `clientId` as a param and then use that to look up the appropriate client. For the user-level permissions, you would simply integrate the user that owns the client object into the query. For example:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var client = db.Clients.SingleOrDefault(m => m.UserId == userId && m.ClientId == clientId);
if (client == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}

// whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been doing the same as you suggested all this while. Actually the client information is broken down in about 10 different classes so i have 10 controllers and 10 views, when I  post data to one controller after updating it redirect to next controller. I feel  something wrong exposing client id in the query string. Is this approach safe or there is some better way?

Comment: The id is just an identifier for the database, if you're using it for anything other than that, then it's a problem. Given that, there's absolutely nothing wrong with including it in the URL. As long as you're using a standard autoincrement PK or a GUID, and not something silly like a social security number, you're fine.

Comment: It is auto increment PK. I'll use id in URL. Thanks.